# WSO2ESB SAML SSO Management Consle sign-out

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, esb, saml, wso2-esb

I'm using the WSO2 ESB version 4.0.3, with some features installed like: Identity Provider, Identity SAML2.0 Single Sign-on, Identity XACML, also BPEL, Data Services Hosting etc.

Following the instructions from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/identity/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+Across+Different+Carbon+Servers), I set up SSO Authentication for the ESB Management Console. The sign-in works just fine, but not the sign-out. In the log I can see the following information:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-06-08 18:12:59,592]  
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator} -  
'admin' logged out at [2012-06-08 18:12:59,0592] 
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator}
```

after what I get errors. Furthermore, in the browser shows like I'm still logged in.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-06-08 18:13:03,581]  
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  
Illegal access attempt at [2012-06-08 18:13:03,0581] from IP address : 
Service is RegistryAdminService {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler}

TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-06-08 18:13:03,584] 
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  
Access Denied. Please login first. {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
...

TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-06-08 18:13:03,599] 
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ui.clients.RegistryAdminServiceClient} -  
Error occurred while checking registry mode {org.wso2.carbon.ui.clients.RegistryAdminServiceClient}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Please login first.
...

TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2012-06-08 18:13:03,879] 
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.ui.ServerAdminClient} -  
Cannot get server data. Backend service may be unavailable {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.ui.ServerAdminClient} 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Please login first.
```

Am I missing something in the configuration? If not, can someone please explain what is happening?

Note: The errors are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

These repetitive errors means you are logged out from the back end, and it tries to refresh a page like Carbon home page or statistics page by invoking the corresponding BE services.

Is WSO2 IS running as a separate node or the necessary IdP features are installed in ESB?

- Thilina

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The IdP features are installed in the ESB.